# How to handle voice from Bluetooth?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, audio-streaming, bluez

I am working on a Raspberry pi based embedded project which turn a raspberry pi to a bluetooth based voice processing system. I have a BLE mic and BLE receiver connected to the RPI, I have BlueZ integrated to my stack. I am able to connect both together. But the problem I am facing now is in handling Audio from the mic. I don't have ALSA or pulse audio in my system. Is there a way to get PCM data from the bluez stack directly? it would be helpful if there is a architecture for handling voice with BLE.

Comment: These kind of questions are probably better off at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. Also, just how is this related to C++ _and_ C _and_ Linux?

Comment: thought I could use something from other devices also

Comment: Are you sure your mic and receiver are BLE?  And not classic bluetooth?  BLE is typically for low power, low bandwidth application which is not suitable for streaming audio between devices.